# mysql: select between

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I am getting invalid use of group function, not really sure where the problem is

expected result is list of timestamps from within xxx seconds starting from the max available

Please advise.

```
SELECT timestamp, response_time 
FROM results
WHERE id = XYZ AND timestamp between 
(SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM results inn WHERE id = 22) AND 
(SELECT timestamp FROM results WHERE id =22 AND timestamp = MAX(timestamp) - XXX)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

thank you

Comment: `XYZ` and `22` are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  timestamp, response_time
FROM    results
WHERE   id = @xyz
        AND timestamp BETWEEN
        ( 
        SELECT  MAX(timestamp)
        FROM    results
        WHERE   id = 22
        ) AND
        ( 
        SELECT  MAX(timestamp)
        FROM    results
        WHERE   id = 22
        ) - @xxx
ORDER BY
        timestamp DESC
```

Make sure you have an index on `(id, timestamp)` for this to work fast.